# unable to use nested ScrollView in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use `ScrollView` inside another ScrollView in react-native and even `FlatList` inside another FlatList. but it doesn't work out! seems its impossible to use vertical `ScrollView` inside another vertical `ScrollView` or use horizontal one in another horizontal one:

```
<ScrollView>
    <View></View>
    <View>
       <ScrollView></SrollView> //---->OOOPPPSSS
    </View>
    <View></View>
</ScrollView>
```

and every time that i ask question about this problem every one say:you cant use `ScrollView` in another one! :| i know i cant but whats the solution? **how can i do the trick** to implement that?

Comment: I have just found [this example](https://snack.expo.io/rk93R9BCW) I wish it helps...

Answer (score 0):

For the outer ScrollView substitute ViewPagerAndroid or https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager (for android only!)

```
<ViewPagerAndroid>  // <-- use this for outer element in Android
    <View></View>
    <View>
       <ScrollView></ScrollView> 
    </View>
    <View></View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```